# How can I merge data of pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, plot, merge

I'd like to merge data of Series. But as result,These data was divided to three. How can I merge these data to one?
(python3 jupyter notebook)

```
fp_price = pd.Series(data)
keep = []
for i in fp_price:
    fp_price_merge = i
    keep.append(fp_price_merge)
print(keep)
```

result

```
[487832.87560916983, 488448.86992150272, 490797.3482372716, 
490127.78920212726, 490493.25684214354, 490632.19034193602]
[481897.10423319356, 482361.70278453565, 482144.11241496605, 
481998.03776126896, 482209.0344832759, 482318.84407537803]
[483650.51656619791, 483357.08254157269, 483476.66114698362, 
483627.19449776667, 483503.16349747358, 483547.58143689478]
```

Comment: show your data ? or fp_price ?

Answer (score 1):

Flatten a list with `sum`:

```
sum(fp_price, [])
```

---

```
In [11]: s = pd.Series([[1, 2], [3]])

In [12]: sum(s, [])
Out[12]: [1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

This will print out a `list` of value.

```
l=fp_price.values.tolist()
import functools
functools.reduce(lambda x,y: x+y,l)
```

Comment: usually you'd use `sum(lst, [])`.

Comment: This got me to rabbit hole of Guido's opinion on reduce, he suggests only to use if the func is an operator e.g. `reduce(operator.mul, lst, 1)`. https://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196

Answer (score 0):

You can use "concat" function. There are lots of variations if you have specific requirements for handling the indices.

Code:

```
fp_price = pd.Series(data)
keep = []
for i in fp_price:
    fp_price_merge = i
    keep.append(fp_price_merge)
result=pd.concat(keep)
print(result)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I tried your way.
but appear error as below.
TypeError: cannot concatenate a non-NDFrame object